# Js is not responding correct informaion

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

**when submit with empty value, there will should be error-msg at both of inputs. However, it is working correctly.**

In side of script is validation for empty value if input empty value error-msg will be changed to display:block

this is the code below, anyone could help me i am very appreciate.

```js
function validation(thisForm) {

  //validation of fName
  if (!thisForm.fname.value.length) {
    document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
  //validation of lName
  if (!thisForm.lname.value.length) //if there is no input to lName
  {
    document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.error-msg {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charest="utf-8">
  <title>error-msg will not display correctly at the same time</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" onSubmit="return validation(this);">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Application Name</legend>
      <div class="name">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
        <span class="error-msg" id="fname-error">First name is required</span>
      </div>

      <div class="name">
        <label for="lname">Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50">
        <span class="error-msg" id="lname-error">Last name is required</span>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />


  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning early in your `validation()` function. Change it to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="456.css">

  <meta charest ="utf-8">
  <title>error-msg will not display correctly at the same time</title>

  <script>
  function validation(thisForm) {
  
//validation of fName
    if(!thisForm.fname.value.length)
    {
      document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display="none";
    }
        //validation of lName
    if(!thisForm.lname.value.length) //if there is no input to lName
    {
      document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display="none";
    }
    if(!thisForm.fname.value.length || !thisForm.lname.value.length)
    {
      return false
    }
    return true;
}
  </script>
  <style> 
  .error-msg {
  display: none;
  color:red;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;

}
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" onSubmit="return validation(this);">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Application Name</legend>
      <div class="name">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
        <span class="error-msg" id="fname-error">First name is required</span>
      </div>

      <div class="name">
        <label for="lname">Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50">
        <span class="error-msg" id="lname-error">Last name is required</span>
      </div>
       
    </fieldset>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
     
   
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```